# Initialize static class member with an instance of a derived class if type is a reference to a pure virtual base class

Tags: c++, static, initializer, static-constructor

When I try to initialize a static member in my `Action.cpp` file via

```
ILogger & Action::m_activeLogger = DefaultLogger();
```

the compiler (C++11 + Linux) says:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type "ILogger &" to an rvalue of type ILogger

How can I initialize my static member variable pointing to the instance?

Minimal example:

I have an interface base class (pure virtual)

**base.h:**

```
class ILogger {
public:
    virtual ~ILogger();
    virtual void write(std::string msg);
}
```

with **DefaultLogger.h** as an derived class as implementation (CPP file not shown here):

```
class DefaultLogger : public ILogger {
public:
    ~DefaultLogger();
    void write(std::string msg);
}
```

In **Action.h** I am using a static member variable with a reference to the base class:

```
class Action {
    static ILogger & m_activeLogger;
    // getter/setter to register another logger...
}
```

How can I initialize the static member variable `m_activeLogger` with my derived class?

Comment: This may be what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your logger not by reference, but with a `unique_ptr` and dereference it for the accessor:

```
class Action {
    static std::unique_ptr<ILogger> m_activeLogger;
    // getter/setter to register another logger...
}
```

And then should have an accessor to get it:

```
ILogger& get_instance(){return * m_activeLogger;}
```

Otherwise, you won't be able to set another logger! At least not with a reference.

Side note, the virtual call should probably take a const& to the string, and then tag them with `override`:

```
void write(const std::string& msg) override;
```

Comment: Thanks for your very valuable response, it took me some time to read the background docs! `unique_ptr` seems to work. I am only having problems to understand the idea behind the `get_instance method. Why returning a pointer to an `unique_ptr` and interpreting it as `ILogger`? Shall it replace the getter **and** setter?  I would add this setter: `void setLogger(std:unqie_ptr<ILogger> newlogger)` (which requires `move()` to pass the argument)...

Comment: Yes, setLogger would get a unique_ptr<ILogger> via more. Then I'm not returning a pointer to a unique_ptr for the get instance, I'm returning a ref to the logger.

Comment: For other readers to understand the idea behind `get_instance`: `*` is overloaded and returns the raw pointer (like `get()`). It is OK not to return an `unique_ptr` since the ownership is not moved and an `unique_ptr` does only guarantee to "free" (delete) the underlying object but **not** meant to solve dangling pointers.